# Issue with Mongodb pre-defined javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I keep getting, `Missing ";" before statement` error in Mongodb Atlas Online. I am new to this, and I fail to see why the following lines gives this error:

```
const counter = await counterCollection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: changeEvent.ns },{ $inc: { seq_value: 1 }}, { returnNewDocument: true, upsert : true});
```

**AND:**

```
const updateRes = await targetCollection.updateOne({_id: docId},{ $set: doc});
```

**Full code:**

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {
  const docId = changeEvent.fullDocument._id;
  
  const counterCollection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db(changeEvent.ns.db).collection("counters");
  const targetCollection = context.services.get("Cluster0").db(changedEvent.ns.db).collection(changeEvent.ns.coll);
  const counter = await counterCollection.findOneAndUpdate({_id: changeEvent.ns },{ $inc: { seq_value: 1 }}, { returnNewDocument: true, upsert : true});
  
  const doc = {};
  doc[`${changeEvent.ns.coll}Id`] = counter.seq_value;
  const updateRes = await targetCollection.updateOne({_id: docId},{ $set: doc});
  console.log(`Updated ${JSON.stringify(changeEvent.ns)} with counter ${counter.seq_value} result: ${JSON.stringify(updateRes)}`);
};
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve it, added `async` in front of function, and this eliminated the errors. Not sure why I not thought about this before. Sorry SO!